# Mapbox Studio- How does Text Halo work?

Tags: mapbox-studio

[image: Mapbox Text Halo]

How do I make text Halo in Mapbox Studio work? I tried different width and blur but the text still the same no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halo is the outline of the label's text.
By clicking Halo color tab you see this window:

[image]

There is a small tab named "a" and must be set to 100 (opacity).

Comment: Thank You! that "a" was a thing i didn't know about..